# Unremovable webpage element?

Tags: css, html

are there any webpage elements, that cannot be removed, e.g. by AdBlock? I was wondering if there's a way to modify webpage content (add an image) that will be shown always, even if someone tries to block or remove it.

Comment: No. It's the user's own browser, they can do whatever they want with it.

Comment: Users cannot unload scripts that have already been loaded. Scripts loaded into memory could create new elements to host new ads, etc. You'd be busy all day long listening for mutation events, and deleting elements.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this is not possible. Because the code is executed at the browser side, the program, user and plugins can modify your code as the want to.

Practically, you could design your element in a way AdBlock doesn't recognize that it should be blocked. But there is now HowTo on this topic.
[Here](https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7551) you find a list with criteria for acceptable ads. You should see this as a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of an element that *can't* be removed. But if the issue is one-off removal, then scripts can work around that by being prepared to create new elements, as often as is necessary.

For instance, I may have a script that seeks out a pre-existing host element to load its ads into. If that host element is not found, my script could create one, and append it as a new child to the document. You could delete the `<script>` element from the page, but once my code has been executed, you will have a tough time stopping it, especially if I don't expose any of it to the global scope.

While this wouldn't yield *unremoveable* elements, it would yield persistent scripted elements.